# php snippets in html are being commented out

Tags: php

when i try to add an element to a site, that contains a php snippet, it is commented out and not working:

```
function phpTest() {
    return "<p><?php echo 'some text';?></p>"; 
}

add_shortcode("test", "phpTest");
```

when i add `[test]` to a site now and inspect the result i see that

```
<p><!--?php echo 'some text';?--></p>
```

has been generated. Why is that so and what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

You don't display anything in shorcode's function, you just return what has to be displayed. Your code should be:

```
function phpTest() {
    return '<p>some text</p>'; 
}
add_shortcode('test', 'phpTest');
```

**Update**: if your function contains anything, which displays data, use it as follows:

```
function phpTest() {
    ob_start();
    // your code goes here
    return ob_get_clean(); 
}
add_shortcode('test', 'phpTest');
```

Comment: well of course that is how i can replace the echo command, but what if i want to have more complex php-functions inside my html like query an sql database?

Comment: read update to my answer.